# package manager in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been using visual studio code as a second display (with visual studio as the first) to view/edit code mostly JavaScript since you can right click/format the code with easy.

But I recently took to time to study how it's c#/asp.net core debug functionality has evolved and it seems it has become even more easier to start whipping debug in no time.

But there is one thing I haven't figured out and whether it's even possible. That's it managing nuget packages. Visual studio offers a nice [package manager ui](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-ui) to view installed packages and which packages might need a version bump.
[image]

It's there an alternative for visual studio code other than browsing the [nuget site](https://www.nuget.org/) and checking which of your referenced packages have updated and editing the `.csproj` manually or running `dotnet add <project> package ...`?

Answer (score 4):

This is probably not relevant anymore, but for anyone else also searching for something like this, there is a pretty handy extension for VSCode called Package Manager GUI [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aliasadidev.nugetpackagemanagergui).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).